# metasploit: how do I force build database cache

Tags: metasploit

Every time I update from git, the database is invalidated.

```
msf exploit(handler) > search xxx
[!] Module database cache not built yet, using slow search
```

How can I force the database to be built?

And in msfconsole, how can I check the database update status?

Comment: https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/wiki/Setting-Up-a-Metasploit-Development-Environment#set-up-postgresql

Comment: Thanks @void_in, but I didn't find the part answering my question. The only thing it talks about it how to setup a database, which is something I've already done ...

Comment: After you install and start the PostreSQL db, run the command msfdb init

Comment: @void_in Hmm, there's no msfdb command in git version ...

Comment: What is the status of db_status command on the msfconsole?

Comment: `msf > db_rebuild_cache` and give it a few minutes

Answer (score 1):

If you get a "[!] Module database cache not built yet, using slow search" error after updating. Once you disconnect the database connection, you can try to reconnect db.

```
 1. msf > db_status
 2. msf > db_disconnect
 3. msf > db_status
 4. msf > db_connect user:pass@127.0.0.1:5432/dbName
 5. msf > db_rebuild_cache
 6. msf > db_status
 7. msf > search xxx
```

You can try version command maybe help

```
msf > version
```